# Adding event listeners on array of pics in specific way

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom-events

I have a bunch of images, that should be distributed in container one by one, which means **each image shows exact after previous image is loaded and showed**, and each image should get an event listener.
Here is my solution https://jsfiddle.net/e2sfzn1u/4/ 
I have used `Image.onload` to add the image node to the markup and to define event listener for that node, and when these are ready, it goes to another image (recursively).

```
var pics = [
   'http://i.imgur.com/1oT2ZpOb.jpg',
   'http://i.imgur.com/XsViuLib.jpg',
   'http://i.imgur.com/aTDTI8Eb.jpg',
   'http://i.imgur.com/4kLvWOdb.jpg'
]
var cont = document.getElementById('container');
var each = function(arr, i) {
   if (i === undefined) {
      i = 0;
   }
   if (i < arr.length) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
         cont.innerHTML += '<div class="sas" id="' + i + '" ></div>';
         var pic = document.getElementById(i);
         pic.appendChild(img);
         pic.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert('mda')
         });
         each(arr, i + 1);
      };
      img.src = arr[i];
   }
};
each(pics);
```

Looks simple, but there is a problem - event listener is defined only for last element.

Comment: You can try setting onclick attribute to elements, which will store the variable in the attribute `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i came to the solution 
The problem was here

```
cont.innerHTML += '<div class="sas" id="' + i + '" ></div>';
```

I tried to make it somehow like @RoryMcCrossan suggested - i created the div element in the proper way

```
//cont.innerHTML += '<div id="' + i + '"></div>';
var div = cont.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
div.setAttribute('id', i);
div.setAttribute('class','sas');
var pic = document.getElementById(i);
pic.appendChild(img)
div.addEventListener('click', function () {
   alert('mda')
});
```

The only explanation i have is that Element.innerHTML is quite slower than adding elements by node, so I want to give a huge advice to all human kind - never use hardcode innerHTML to manipulate the DOM. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution would be to create all `img` elements in a loop then use a single delegated click event handler on them. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
    $('<img />', {
        'src': pics[i],
        'class': 'sas',
        'data-id': i,
        'load': function() {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            console.log(id + ' img loaded');
        }
    }).appendTo('#container')
}

$('#container img').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e2sfzn1u/6/)

Comment: Instead of disturbing dom inside for loop, you could have used `var elem = $(); for(....){ elem = elem.add($('<img>')) }   elem.appenTo(...) `

Comment: the problem is that event listener should be set, as i already mentioned in intro, right after image is fully loaded (doing it with just a _for_ cycle does not guarantee that)

Comment: @AshotKazaryan it makes no difference. The event is still present on the element at the point it is created.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan unfortunately, it makes, because my particular event listeners are doing some computations, based on these images dimensions (so thats why they should be loaded beforehand)

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the `click` event. I updated my answer for you to include the `load()` event handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as far as I know, jquery's onload fires when corresponding element is added to markup, not when it is loaded, thats why i'm using that snippet with Image.onload